# Make an input type file from jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I want to set html "input type file" from javascript. but when the upload function executed it return error.

Array
(
    [error] =>

You did not select a file to upload.

)

script file :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#amandemen').html('<input type="file" name="amandemen">');
</script>
```

html form :

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('Project/upload_dokumen', 'id="form-upload"');?>

<td><span id="amandemen"></span></td>
</form>
```

but when i set the input type file from html it's work fine :

```
<td><span id="amandemen"><input type="file" name="amandemen"></span></td>
```

what did i miss ?

Comment: I believe you are using jQuery. It might help more people help you if you included that as a tag and changed the question heading :) Also, have you included the jQuery file BEFORE your `<script>` element?

Comment: @adamoffat hey thanks for ur suggestin. ya i did include it

Comment: Can you provide the script that is being used to retrieve the `$_FILES` array?

Comment: Can you provide a full example of your HTML? I ask as you have a `</form>` element next to a `</td>` which is invalid, and would potentially result in the input being rendered outside of the form, which may cause the behaviour you're seeing

Answer (score 0):

You must put your javascript code into document ready like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#amandemen').html('<input type="file" name="amandemen">');
});
```